# How to generate a log record in a comma separated format

Tags: linux, awk, redhat, centos8

Earlier I am using this command which generates a record in the space-separated format

```
sudo cat path of the file |
awk -v d="$(date --date="1 days ago" +"%h %e")" ' 
    /Accepted/ && ($0 ~ d) { print $1,$2,$9,$11}' |
sort | uniq -c
```

like this

```
xx xx xx xxxx xxx
xx xx xx xxxx xxx
```

Now my aim is to generate a comma-separated record for that I'm using this way

```
sudo cat path of the file |
awk -v d="$(date --date="1 days ago" +"%h %e")" ' 
    /Accepted/ && ($0 ~ d) { print $1","$2","$9","$11}' |
sort | uniq -c
```

but it is giving me the record like this

```
xx xx,xx,xxxx,xxx
xx xx,xx,xxxx,xxx
```

I want to achieve a comma after the first column so on.
How can I do it help, please

Comment: Note that it is a good idea to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name. That means not only including your code and the desired and actual outputs (you did that), but it also means including the input data that was used to get those outputs.  Then people can test their code on your data.  It also makes the `sudo cat /var/log/secure` unnecessary since you can show the command reading a file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this if anyone has a better approach  then do tell me

```
sudo cat path of the file |
awk -v d="$(date --date="1 days ago" +"%h %e")" ' 
    /Accepted/ && ($0 ~ d) { print $1,$2,$9,$11}' |  
sort | uniq -c | sed -E -e 's/^[[:blank:]]+//g' -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g'
```

Comment: Note that the `g` in `'s/^[[:blank:]]+//g'` is superfluous (harmless but unnecessary).  There's only one start of line, so the match can't repeat, so there's no point in using `g`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `uniq -c` prefixes the count to the line, separating the count from the data with a space (and usually including spaces before the count, at least for counts up to 3 digits long on a Mac, 6 digits long on RHEL 7.4).  So, if there is no way to change the separator (there isn't on a Mac; and `uniq` 8.22 on RHEL 7.4 does not include such an option), then you'll have to do it yourself.

However, you can use `awk` to do the counting and formatting, leaving an optional sort for post-processing:

```sh
sudo cat /var/log/secure |
awk -v d="$(date --date="1 days ago" +"%h %e")" ' 
    /Accepted/ && ($0 ~ d) { key = $1 "," $2 "," $9 "," $11; count[key]++ }
    END { for (key in count) print count[key] ",", key }'
```

<sup>*Warning: untested code — there isn't any usable sample data in the question!*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use "sed" and replace whitespace with ,. Here is simple echo statement to do that

```
[user@hostname ~]$ echo "xx xx xx xxxx xxx" | sed 's/ /,/g'
xx,xx,xx,xxxx,xxx
```

Similarly you can use another pipe at end and do sed something like

```
sudo cat path of the file |
awk -v d="$(date --date="1 days ago" +"%h %e")" ' 
    /Accepted/ && ($0 ~ d) { print $1,$2,$9,$11}' |
sort | uniq -c | sed 's/ /,/g'
```